# With Angular 7 use HTTP API for POST and command error headers missing

Tags: angular, cors, orientdb

I use Angular 7 and Orientdb 3.0.14.
I want connect to my database demodb in localhost.

this my code for command :

```
command(statement: string, success: (data: any) => void, error: (err: any) => void): void {
    this.url = this.url + 'sql/-/-1';
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200')
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE')
      .set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600')
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, authorization')
      .set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(this.username + ':' + this.password))
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      console.log(this.headers);
    this.http.post(this.url,
      JSON.stringify({'command': statement}),
      {headers: this.headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(success)
      .catch(error);
```

but i have this error on console:

> HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: Array(7), headers:
>   Map(0), lazyInit: HttpHeaders}headers:
>
> Map(7)size: (...)**proto**:
>   Map[[Entries]]:
>
> Array(7)0: {"access-control-allow-origin" =>
>   Array(1)}key: "access-control-allow-origin"value:
>   ["http://localhost:4200"]1: {"access-control-allow-methods" =>
>
> Array(1)}key: "access-control-allow-methods"value: ["POST, GET,
>   OPTIONS, DELETE"]
>
> 2: {"access-control-max-age" => Array(1)}key:
>   "access-control-max-age"value: ["3600"]
>
> 3:{"access-control-allow-credentials" => Array(1)}key:
>   "access-control-allow-credentials"value: ["true"]
>
> 4:{"access-control-allow-headers" => Array(1)}key:
>   "access-control-allow-headers"value: ["Content-Type, authorization"]
>
> 5:{"authorization" => Array(1)}key: "authorization"value: ["Basic
>   YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="]
>
> 6: {"content-type" => Array(1)}key:
>   "content-type"value: ["application/json"]length: 7lazyInit:
>   nulllazyUpdate: nullnormalizedNames:
>   Map(7) {"access-control-allow-origin" =>
>   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "access-control-allow-methods" =>
>   "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "access-control-max-age" =>
>   "Access-Control-Max-Age", "access-control-allow-credentials" =>
>   "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "access-control-allow-headers" =>
>   "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", …}
>
> **proto**: Object core.js:16819
>   Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to
>   enable the production mode. localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost:2480/command/demodb/sql/-/-1' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

see Access-Control_allow-Origin is into header..but not accepted by OriendDB

Can you help me ?
thanks.

Comment: It's your backend that needs to allow CORS.

Comment: i dont have the bakend, only frontend (angular) call directly orientdb all in localhost.
i try it.

Comment: workaround would  be open chrome below command by run and try to access chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security

Comment: I have added the answer please accept if finds helpful so that others will get benefit out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OrientDB CORS is not enabled by default and the way you trying to achieve not helpful.

Add this entry in `config/orientdb-server-config.xml`

```
<parameter name="network.http.additionalResponseHeaders" value="Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ;Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true;Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type;Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, CONNECT, TRACE " />
```

above

```
<parameter value="utf-8" name="network.http.charset"/>
```

It's also important to not use space after the colon `;`

Comment: ok ok, i have remove set headers all ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW in client app angular, and now is ok. 
Thnaks